Why is removing a google map Polyline not working for google maps
I have a bug where  when I plot a polyline on a google map and I try to remove it It is not removed. I am wondering if this seems to be because I am using pinia.
And how would I go about it
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import { ref, watch } from 'vue';

export const useMapStore = defineStore('map', () => {
    const mapContainer = ref(null);
    const googleMap = ref(null);
    const googlePolyline = ref(null)


    watch([() => googlePolyline.value ], ([newGooglePolyline],[oldGooglePolyline]) => {
      if(oldGooglePolyline){
          oldGooglePolyline.setMap(null)
      }
      if(newGooglePolyline){
          newGooglePolyline.setMap(googleMap.value)
      }
    })

    const plotHistory = (locations, currentPosition, pathId = null ) => {
        locations = locations.map((position) => {
            return { lat: position.latitude, lng: position.longitude }
        })
        // Draw lines connecting the markers
        googlePolyline.value = new google.maps.Polyline({
          path: locations,
          strokeColor: "#FF0000",
          strokeOpacity: 1.0,
          strokeWeight: 2,
        });
    }


    const clearPolyline = () => {
        if (googlePolyline.value) {
            googlePolyline.value = null;
        }
    }


}


It seems like multiple lines might be. being created but I can't seem to figure out if this is the case.
Here a GitHub link to a minimal project I have created to reproduce the issue.
https://github.com/iamafasha/google-map-vue-pinia

It seems like multiple lines a new Polyline is created every time you call new google.maps.Polyline() how hard would it be to debug that? Please provide a [mcve] that allows to reproduce the issue, along with debugging details.

Try to put debuggers and logs and it doesn't seem like any logic that plots the polyline is running twice. This is either because of how pinna works in the background or vuejs.

@MrUpsidown will try to create a play vue project with pinia with this and I see

The other thing is clicking the button that removes the polyline seems to remove it but then when you do any other action on the map like zooming in it re-appears. again I tried to log but no log was logged when the polyline reappeared.

@MrUpsidown here is the link to the minimal reproducible example
https://github.com/iamafasha/google-map-vue-pinia

Turns out it's because of how vue creates proxy objects. as John mentions in his answer to this question.
Here is what I did to fix the issue
watch([() => googlePolyline.value ], ([newGooglePolyline][oldGooglePolyline]) => {
      if(oldGooglePolyline){
        console.log("oldGooglePolyline set to null", oldGooglePolyline)
        toRaw(oldGooglePolyline).setMap(null)
      }
      if(newGooglePolyline){
        console.log("newGooglePolyline set to googleMap")
          toRaw(newGooglePolyline).setMap(googleMap.value)
      }
    })

So I had to use the toRaw method provided by vue, to access the actual object created by vue instead of using the Proxy.
Here is the documentation on it.
